# Highest Value from DataSet in Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

this is What have so far.

```
function GetHighest () {
    var arrayData = [];
    var data = $("#QuarterlyBucketsGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        arrayData.push(data[i].max);
    }
    return arrayData;
};
```

I want to get the Highest value from the grid , and set my kendo text box default value to highest value from kendo grid. please help me

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions
1) Apply sorting from server side and get highest value of column on top.

OR

2) You have to sort your "data" variable on a specific dataset attribute. Also note kendo already have compare() functions that you can use.